# SQL IN Statement Slowness

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having some trouble getting my SQL to run efficiently with an IN statement.  If I run the two statements separately, and manually paste in the series of results (in this case there are 30 vendor_id's) the vendor_master query runs instantly, and the invoices query runs in about 2 seconds.

```
select * FROM invoices where vendor_id IN

(

select vendor_id from vendor_master WHERE vendor_master_id = 12345

);
```

So what causes the HUGE slowdown, more than 60 seconds and often times out?  Is there a way to put the results in a variable with commas?  Or to get the inner statement to execute firsT?

Comment: Minor note. You're missing the `WHERE` keyword in the subquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *So what causes the HUGE slowdown, more than 60 seconds and often times out?*

The `IN` clause works well when the data set inside the `IN` condition is "small" and "deterministic". That's because the condition is evaluated *once* per row. So, assuming that the query in the `IN` clause returns 100 rows and the table in the `FROM` clause has 1000 rows, the server will have to perform `100 * 1000 = 100,000` comparissons to filter out your data. Too much effort to filter too little data, don't you think? Of course, if your data sets (both in `from` and `in` clauses) are bigger, you can imagine the effect.

By the way, when you use a subquery as an `in` condition, there's also an additional overhead: the subquery needs to be executed *once*  for each row. So the sequence is something like this:

- row 1

  - execute subquery
  - check if the value of row 1 matches a value of the result of the subquery
  - if the above is true, keep the row in the result set; exclude it otherwise
- row 2

  - execute subquery
  - check if the value of row 2 matches a value of the result of the subquery
  - if the above is true, keep the row in the result set; exclude it otherwise
- ...

Too much work to do, don't you think?

---

> *Is there a way to put the results in a variable with commas?*

Yes, there's a way... but would you *really* want to do that? Let's see:

First, create a list with the values you want to filter:

```
set @valueList = (select group_concat(vendor_id separator ',')
                 from (select vendor_id from vendor_master where vendor_master_id = 12345) as a)
```

Then, create an SQL expression:

```
set @sql = concat('select * from invoices where vendor_id in (', @valueList, ')';
```

Finally, create a prepared statement and execute it:

```
prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
-- when you're done, don't forget to deallocate the statement:
-- deallocate prepare stmt;
```

I ask you again: do you *really* want to do all this?

---

> *Or to get the inner statement to execute first?*

All the other answers are pointing you in the right direction: instead of using `in` use `inner join`:

```
select i.*
from invoices as i
     inner join (
         select distinct vendor_id 
         from vendor_master
         where vendor_master_id = 12345
     ) as vm on i.vendor_id = vm.vendor_id;
```

If, for some reason, this still is too slow, the only alternative that comes to my mind is: Create a temporary table (sort of "divide-and-conquer strategy"):

```
drop table if exists temp_vm;
create temporary table temp_vm
    select distinct vendor_id
    from vendor_master
    where vendor_master_id = 12345;
alter table temp_vm
    add index vi(vendor_id);
select i.*
from invoices as i inner join temp_vm as vm on i.vendor_id = vm.vendor_id;
```

Remember: temp tables are only visible to the connection that creates them, and are dropped when the connection is closed or terminated.

---

In any case, your performance will be improved if you ensure that your tables are properly indexed; specifically, you need to ensure that `invoices.vendor_id` and vendor_master.vendor_master_id` are indexed.

Comment: Is there a reason when I run the statements separate and make my own comma separated list that it runs very very fast, its still having to evaluate each value of the IN array right?

Comment: consider this: for every row in your `invoices` table, the `in` condition is evaluated once, and that `in` condition is a query that has to be evaluated... too much load! When you pass a simple comma-separated list of values, there's no need to evaluate a query... still, it's too much! Use `inner join` instead of `in` (cleaner, faster and cheaper)

Answer (score 3):

Prior to MySQL 5.6.6, `in` was optimized quite inefficiently.  Use `exists` instead:

```
select *
FROM invoices i
where exists (select 1
              from vendor_master vm
              where i.vendor_id = vm.vendor_id and vm.vendor_master_id = 12345
             );
```

For best performance, you want an index on `vendor_master(vendor_id, vendor_master_id)`.

Comment: Not to mention the problem if vendor_id is null

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `INNER JOIN`:

```
select i.* 
FROM invoices i
INNER JOIN vendor_master vm 
        ON i.vendor_id = vm.vendor_id AND vm.vendor_master_id = 12345
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JOIN` with `DISTINCT` instead of `IN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM invoices JOIN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT vendor_id as vid
    FROM vendor_master
    WHERE vendor_master_id = 12345
) vmi
ON invoices.vendor_in = vmi.vid
```

Remember that you have to have the `DISTINCT`, otherwise if there are two records for the inner query, than you will have repeated rows after the `JOIN`, and the result will be different from `IN` query.